# Git credential-manager-core not working in VSCode DevContainer

Tags: git, docker, vscode-devcontainer

i´m currently experimenting with VSCode´s DevContainer. As for my purpose, i tried to configure a container for my existing Azure Function. Below you can find my Dockerfile, my docker-compose.yml and my devcontainer.json.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated6.0-core-tools

COPY --from=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim /usr/share/dotnet /usr/share/dotnet
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  functionapp:
    container_name: functionapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    volumes:
      - ${USERPROFILE}/.azure:/root/.azure
      - ${APPDATA}/NuGet:/root/.nuget/NuGet

    environment:
      - AzureWebJobsStorage=UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://172.24.0.99

    networks:
      functionapp-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.24.0.5
          

  azurite: 
    container_name: storage.emulator
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "10000:10000"
      - "10001:10001"
      - "10002:10002"

    networks:
      functionapp-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.24.0.99

networks:
  functionapp-network:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "172.24.0.0/16"
```

devcontainer.json:

```
{
    "name": "functionapp-container",
    "dockerComposeFile": ["docker-compose.yml","docker-compose.extend.yml"],
    "service": "functionapp",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",
    "forwardPorts": [ 7071 ],

    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions",
                "ms-dotnettools.csharp",
                "nhoizey.gremlins",
                "oderwat.indent-rainbow",
                "donjayamanne.githistory",
                "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker",
                "ms-azuretools.vscode-azurestorage"
            ]
        }
    },
    
    "postCreateCommand": "dotnet restore",

    "features": {
        "git": "latest",
        "azure-cli": "latest",
        "dotnet-cli":"latest"
    }
}
```

As you can see, my whole approach is very minimalistic, the problem is, that i´m not able to connect to my Azure DevOps Repo without entering Credentials/a PAT. As described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_sharing-git-credentials-with-your-container) all git configurations from my local machine should be forwarded to my container. I can confirm that this is happening with my .gitconfig, as it is the same in my container and my local machine.

.gitconfig:

```
[difftool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = '' \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = "'' "
    trustExitCode = true
[credential "helperselector"]
    selected = manager-core
[user]
    name = myUsername
    email = My@email.com
[core]
    longpaths = true
[filter "lfs"]
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
[fetch]
    prune = false
[pull]
    rebase = false
[http]
    sslbackend = openssl
[credential]
    helper = 
    helper = manager-core
[credential "https://dev.azure.com"]
    usehttppath = true
```

Note: my local git is working perfectly fine, without the need to reenter any credentials. Furthermore in my container i´m getting the errornote "git: 'credential-manager-core' is not a git command. See 'git --help'." in my git output log, while the login prompt is showing.

Comment: your local machine is Windows or WSL2?

Comment: It´s windows 10, WSL2 ist installed but not used by me

Comment: I think auto-forwarding of git socket only compatible with WSL2 but not for Windows. You can try with WSL2 filesystem instead.

Comment: Ref. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_sharing-git-credentials-with-your-container